# Map collection separate Object values

Tags: java, collections

I have a Map collection that stores "stops" as Key and a set of grid and time results as an Object value. e.g.

```
Key: [stops]
Value: [[{grid_item=Grid1, time=09:30}, {grid_item=Grid13, time=10:00}, {grid_item=Grid3, time=10:15}, {grid_item=Grid10, time=10:35}]]
```

Is there a way to separate the Value results, because i would like to use the grid_item and time to send them to another method. How can i get those values specifically?

Or should i store again the values in a Map but now the keys are grid_item and time. But how can i do that?

Any Suggestions?

Comment: Can you use java 8 ?

Comment: Would calling the `values` method on your `Map` not achieve what you want here? It will return your values in a `Collection`.

Comment: can you please provide a more detailed example input and the exact desired output for that input.

Comment: here you go http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33632090/map-collection-separate-object-values-part2 .Please have a look Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can access a specific object in your `value`'s array this way:

```
map.get(stops)[0] // grid_item=Grid1, time=09:30
map.get(stops)[1] // grid_item=Grid13, time=10:00
....
```

where `stops` is the **key** that you are using.

Comment: I decided to add the code. Could you please have a look. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33632090/map-collection-separate-object-values-part2 Thank you. If possible could you write down an example Thank you